# Base58 javascript implementation

Tags: javascript, ipfs, base58

I am using IPFS-multihash method to store IPFS hash in smart contracts.
For that I need to decode base58 format:

```
QmaozNR7DZHQK1ZcU9p7QdrshMvXqWK6gpu5rmrkPdT3L4
```

to binary(as hex):

```
1220b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9
```

But I am unable to use bs58 module in browser (I tried using Browserify). Can you tell me the javascript implementation for decoding and encoding in base58 so that I can implement the above method without using node_modules?
Or can you tell how exactly can I use Browserify to use a node module step-by-step?

After running the first command 'bs58' folder is created in 'node_modules' folder.....there is no lib folder. Can you guide me with the exact commands I must use?

```
npm install --save bs58

npm install -g browserify

browserify < lib/bs58.js > lib/bs85.bundle.js
```

My file structure is somewhat like this:

```
-node_modules
-src
  |___index.html
  |___js
      |____app.js
```

Comment: Use this for instance? https://gist.github.com/diafygi/90a3e80ca1c2793220e5/

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG. It worked! Just had to convert it into Hex String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it worked by using  [Base58 implementation](https://gist.github.com/diafygi/90a3e80ca1c2793220e5/) and converting the resulting result into hex.

```
var MAP = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var decoded = toHexString(from_b58(ipfsHash,MAP)).toUpperCase();
```

Thanks to [Chris G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, handling Base58 alone may not be enough.

Consider using official  [cids](https://github.com/ipld/js-cid) library to future-proof your contracts.

IPFS content identifiers are called CIDs ([docs](https://github.com/multiformats/cid#motivation)). Current default is CIDv0 (equal to a raw multihash in Base58btc), but CIDv1 are an opt-in upgrade already used in the wild (it allows encoding to arbitrary bases). [IPFS it will switch to CIDv1 in Base32](https://github.com/ipfs/ipfs/issues/337) as the new default in the future (but everyone will be free to use other base if they wish to do so):

```
<cidv0> ::= <multihash-content-address>
<cidv1> ::= <multibase-prefix><cid-version><multicodec-content-type><multihash-content-address>
```

To convert full IPFS CID to hex with `cids` library, you would do something like:

```
const cidHex = new CID('bafkreigh2akiscaildcqabsyg3dfr6chu3fgpregiymsck7e7aqa4s52zy').buffer.toString('hex').toUpperCase()
```

or if you only care about raw multihash, you can extract it from CID via `.multihash`:

```
const mhHex = new CID('bafkreigh2akiscaildcqabsyg3dfr6chu3fgpregiymsck7e7aqa4s52zy').multihash.toString('hex').toUpperCase()
```

The [`cids` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cids) should work fine with browserify and other bundlers.
There is a [prebuilt version for the browser](https://github.com/multiformats/js-cid#in-the-browser-through-script-tag) as well.

Hope this helps :)